# Set notification in Android on specific days of week (days can be continuous or discontinuous)

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, weekday

I am building an app that takes input from user as days and then set notification for that days of week. Suppose for Wednesday and Friday every week at 2pm. I have used the code.

```
    Calendar setcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    setcalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    setcalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    setcalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        if (day=="1") {
            setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        }
        else if (day=="2")
        {
            setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
        }
        else if(day=="3")
        {
            setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
        }
        else if(day=="4")
        {
            setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);
        }
        else if(day=="5")
        {
            setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
        }
        else if(day=="6")
        {
            setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
        }
        else
        {
            setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        }

         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) 
         context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 

         am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                setcalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7, 
                                pendingIntent);
```

I run the above code for each of the day separately. This code runs for **day=Monday** and then for **day=Wednesday**.

It will set the time and day and then in `setInexactRepeating` it will set each of the notification to occur after every 7 days using `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7`. When I tested the code it is generating the notification for today as well even if "Today is Monday and Monday is not selected by user."

Comment: please post code where you have initiated `pendingIntent`.

Comment: Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, cls);
 intent1.putExtra("id",id);   
final int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Comment: `notificationId` is unique for all of your alarms you are setting? Suppose you have selected Monday and wednesday then `notificationId` should be different for both case.

Comment: Yes it is different.